# How do I search for multiple file types on Google Search Appliance

Tags: file, google-search-appliance

I want to search for multiple file types at once. For example, when I want to search for ".htm" files, I add "filetype:htm" to the query and that works fine. Similarly, "filetype:html" also works. However, how can I specify a query parameter that returns all htm AND html files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The query prefix filetype: filters the results to include only documents with the specified file extension. No spaces can come between filetype: and the specified extension.
>
> You can specify multiple file types by adding filetype: terms to the search query, combined with the Boolean OR.

[Search Protocol Reference](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#filetype)

Answer (score 10):

Be careful, with parenthesis, it doesn't work!

If your query is `filetype:doc OR filetype:pdf` you will have .pdf or .doc into you results,

but if you type `(filetype:doc OR filetype:pdf)` you will only have .doc file types!

Answer (score 4):

QUERY filetype:html OR filetype:htm